# old .pst files on a networked drive still being accessed

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A few months back I have set up email accounts exchange using AD on a domain all is fine. (email, address books ,calendars etc.)

But I left the old .pst files on a networked drive. For some reason outlook the clients are still accessessing the old .pst not for (email, address books ,calendars).

I have removed an account with no adverse effect as a test.

But can any one tell me why outlook is still accessing the old .pst, as I was going to delete all the old .pst files until they all had todays timestamp on.

Comment: I moved the files and they all seem to work fine.  Still don't know what caused acces they were acces on when outlook was opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files were being accessed by Outlook programme why I don't know.